# Error in SQLite, JSON, for Android Program

Tags: android, json, sqlite

What I am trying to achieve is a registration script for an app I am working on, once the user clicks register it updates an external mysql database using php (works fine) and then also stores into a local sqllite database on the device. The error I am getting is this:

```
04-01 11:09:30.553    8592-8667/com.zelphe.zelpheapp E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"dave","lname":"test","email":"test@gmail.com"}}
04-01 11:09:30.613    8592-8592/com.zelphe.zelpheapp W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for dave
```

I am at a bit of a loss of what this actually means / I have to fix?

there shouldn't be a value for dave as dave is the value? As far as I can see the registration has gone fine?

Edit - Code Added

Ok, this is the activity that is running when it gets stuck

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(userFirstName), json_user.getString(userLastName), json_user.getString(userEmail));
                        /**
                         *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                         **/
                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /**
                         * Close Login Screen
                         **/
                        finish();
```

logout user:

```
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }
```

adduser:

```
public void addUser(String userFirstName, String userLastName, String userEmail) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, userFirstName); // FirstName
        values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, userLastName); // LastName
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, userEmail); // Email




        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: Post you json parsing code, may be you altered the tag name in "fname":"dave".

Comment: Don't just post logcat output. Post the code which is causing the error.

Comment: Logic Code update to understand What is the problem in your code

Comment: code now added, still at a bit of a loss even after everyones helpful posts, from what I can see I have basically done what is in the comments. I have updated all my tags etc to match the name in the tables as well, but still no luck, I guess the issue is why is it seeing dave as a token and not the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that it was actually a lot simplier than I was thinking:

```
db.addUser(json_user.getString(userFirstName), json_user.getString(userLastName), json_user.getString(userEmail));
```

this is asking for the keys, where I was sending the values!

should be

```
db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL));
```

I have also added a uid key here now as well which was not in the original

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
{                                       //Main JSONObject
    "tag": "register",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "user": {                           //User JSONObject
        "fname": "dave",
        "lname": "test",
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

Log.v("tag",""+json.getString("tag"));
Log.v("success",""+json.getString("success"));
Log.v("error",""+json.getString("error"));

JSONObject JObj = json.getJSONObject("user");

Log.v("fname",""+JObj.getString("fname"));
Log.v("lname",""+JObj.getString("lname"));
Log.v("email",""+JObj.getString("email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error say , `no value for dave`. its mean you are trying to get value of `dave`. whereas 
**Dave** is a `value` , and you need a `key` to get value. in your case `fname` is a `key` therefore you need to write

```
JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("user");
String fname = obj.getString("fname");
```

and now **fname** has `Dave` in it.

Comment: Hi, I have added my code, as you can see I already have something like this

Answer (score 0):

On observation of the given json looks fine as checked and validated at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

```
{
  "tag": "register",
  "success": 1,
  "error": 0,
  "user": {
    "fname": "dave",
    "lname": "test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

however may be you have a problem at parsing code so use the  below given code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

String tag=json.getString("tag");
int success=json.getInt("success");
int error=json.getInt("error");

JSONObject JObj = json.getJSONObject("user");

String fname=JObj.getString("fname");
String lname=JObj.getString("lname");
String email=JObj.getString("email");
```